# create argc argv in the code

Tags: c++, argv, argc

Hi very newbie question but I just can't figure it out:

I have a function named bar

```
class foo
{
    public:
        bool bar(int argc, char** argv);
}
```

argv is supposed to contain

```
"--dir" and "/some_path/"
```

How do I create argv and argc so that I can pass them into bar() ? I've tried many ways but I just can't get pointer and type conversion right.

So instead of getting argv from command line, I want to create it in the code.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: you create?? no! you can pass arguments to your program through argv. argc is the number of parameters passed in. argv can hold anything values, paths...

Comment: @Raindrop7, sometimes you have to create argc and argv inside of a programm. For example if you want to use boost unit test, you will eventually call main. And on android (if you want to run tests on device) you have to call it yourself and you have to form arguments for it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My favourite way is like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> arguments = {"--dir", "/some_path"};

std::vector<char*> argv;
for (const auto& arg : arguments)
    argv.push_back((char*)arg.data());
argv.push_back(nullptr);

f.bar(argv.size() - 1, argv.data());
```

Note, that if arguments are static and do not change, then this is a little bit overkill. But this approach has advantage of being RAII compliant. It manages memory for you and deletes objects at right moment. So if argument list is dynamic, then it is the cleanest way.

Beside that, this code technically is UB if `f.bar` modifies data in argv array. Usually this is not the case.

Comment: implicit conversion from `const char *` to `char *` again.

Comment: I've made conversion explicit and added notice about UB.

Comment: For c++11 you can use lvalue reference and `&arg[0]` without any cast. Anyway I would prefer `const_cast<>` rather than C-style cast.

Comment: you have a typo in `for (const auto& arg : arguemnts)` should be `arguments`

Comment: Thank you, Ivan. I've fixed the typo.

Comment: Ensure that `argv` doesn't outlive `arguments` or you will have a use-after-free bug.

Comment: Instead of const-casting you can simply use the non-const version of [`std::string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) since C++17

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want argc and argv in the same format that are passed to `main`, you can call it like this:

```
foo f;
char *args[] = {
    (char*)"--dir",
    (char*)"/some_path/",
    NULL
};
f.bar(2, args);
```

(note: this assumes `bar` won't modify the argument strings - in which case you should change the argument type to `const char **` instead of `char **`)

Comment: Conversion from `const char *` to `char *` is illegal in c++

Comment: segfault! no allocation for argv

Comment: @Slava No, it's not. The conversion, if made explicit by a cast, is valid in all versions of C++. Until C++11, the conversion could also be performed implicitly, but only for string literals (which this answer has). Only attempts to modify the pointed-to string are invalid.

Comment: @Raindrop7 argv is an array of pointers. Array is on stack, no allocation needed. Pointers are pointers to constants located in data section. No allocation needed either.

Comment: @AlexeyGuseynov yes you can pass arguments to another functions even main for example in winmain returns a call to main passing to it argc and argv.

Comment: "Attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior: they may be stored in read-only storage (such as .rodata) or combined with other string literals" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal